# What Tool is Equivalent to Perform Manual Join in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, attribute-joins

Using ArcGIS 10.4, what Tool is the equivalent to performing manual join in ArcMap between a Vector Feature Class and a Table?

I tried to create a GIS Model in ModelBuilder and I need to Join a shapefile to a .dbf table so I used `Add Join` from the Toolbox which looks is for Raster datasets!

Comment: What precisely have you tried and what is the error that you are receiving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Add join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-join.htm) is for feature classes and tables as well. Make sure you are providing a feature layer and not a feature class to Add Join. A feature layer is created with [Make Feature Layer tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-feature-layer.htm) or by adding the shapefile and table to ArcMap.

Comment: I think you should quote Desktop rather than Pro documentation in an answer to an ArcMap question.